# Varnish dont work when I call the Vhost

Tags: apache2, varnish, vhosts, varnish-vcl, varnish-4

I have varnish running fine when I call it from ip:port (port = 6081 ) 
But when I try to call it from its Vhost (exp.example) i have the website running without varnish!

My default.vlc

`backend tcook {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "80";
}`

Vhost:

```
    <VirtualHost *:8080>
        Servername  exp.example
        DocumentRoot /my/path
        CustomLog /../..
        ErrorLog /../.. 

</VirtualHost>
```

Ive tried many solutions on the internet but no luck!

Comment: What did you expect? When you call ```exp.example```, the request will not flow through Varnish if you have not set Varnish to listen on port 80

Comment: @DanielV. When i set Varnish to listen on port 80 the caching dont work, I didnt mention that I'm using it in an Ezpublish website, and varnish V3.

Comment: How did you confirm that caching didn't work? Naturally you have to develop your own VCL for caching "to work".